# Handling mutiple GCM messages to single device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

In my application GCM message is initially showed in notification bar .On clicking on that notification it takes to my application activity which will display the message received through GCM.In case if I am reading the GCM message in my application activity and I receive another GCM message which will be first showed in notification area .If I click on the new notification it should start the intended activity of my application and pass on the data to it and destroy itself.But instead of this behavior what's happening is :If I am already reading GCM message  and click on the new notification which I have just received ,it just shows me the already running activity with old message and also not destroying the notification.

My code for handling Notification is:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                DataAccessServer.PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WarningDetails.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("warning", msg);
        bundle.putInt("warningId", NOTIFICATION_ID);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.weather_alert_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Weather Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
        String selectedSound = prefs.getString("selectedSound", "");
        if (!selectedSound.equals("")) {
            Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(selectedSound);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        } else {
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
                    .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        }

        if (prefs.getBoolean("isVibrateOn", false)) {
            long[] pattern = { 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500 };
            mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
        }

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

WarningDetails activity code is :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.warning_details);
        warning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.warningDetails);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String warningData = extras.getString("warning");
            //if (extras.getInt("warningId") != 0) {
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
            //}

            if (warningData != null) {
                warning.setText(warningData);
            } else {
                // Do nothing
            }

        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

I need to show the new notification data and destroy the notification also.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel (destroy) the notification when it's tapped, you should add `.setAutoCancel(true)` to the `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

To update your activity with the data from the new notification you have to move your logic from `onCreate` to `onResume`, since on create is only called when the activity is created, and if the activity already exists when you tap the new notification, the existing activity is used.